# Chekbox com filtros

Tags: c#

Tenho uma consulta de estoque no C# que gera um relatório com reportviewer. Tenho um CheckBox que quando clico nele ele não me mostra os itens com saldo zerado e quando desmarco ele mostra os itens com saldo zerado.

Sendo que ainda tenho 2 filtros que ele tem que seguir, mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar os filtros quando desmarco o CheckBox e quando o CheckBox está marcado o relatório funciona normalmente, quando esta desmarcado os filtros não funcionam mais.

Sendo que a *query* no SQL funciona perfeitamente, tanto passando o parâmetro 1 quanto 0.

segue o codigo

```
private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pSaldo = cbEstoque.Checked == true ? "1" : "0";

    this.SaldoEstoqueTableAdapter.Fill_EstProd(this.Estoque.SaldoEstoque, cbTipo.Text, cbArmazem.Text, pSaldo);

    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

segue a consulta no sql

```
DECLARE @SALDO VARCHAR(10)
SET @SALDO = 0

SELECT       
   SB.B2_COD, 
   S1.B1_DESC, 
   S1.B1_TIPO, 
   SB.B2_LOCAL, 
   (SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) AS SALDO
FROM SB2020 AS SB 
    INNER JOIN SB1020 AS S1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON S1.B1_COD = SB.B2_COD
WHERE SB.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND S1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND S1.B1_TIPO = 'MP' AND SB.B2_LOCAL = '01'
AND ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) >= 0 AND @SALDO = 0) OR ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) > 0 AND @SALDO = 1)
AND S1.B1_TIPO = 'MP' AND SB.B2_LOCAL = '01'
ORDER BY S1.B1_DESC
```

---

Rovann ficou com erro a query

```
SELECT       
   SB.B2_COD, 
   S1.B1_DESC, 
   S1.B1_TIPO, 
   SB.B2_LOCAL, 
   (SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) AS SALDO
FROM SB2020 AS SB 
    INNER JOIN SB1020 AS S1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON S1.B1_COD = SB.B2_COD
WHERE SB.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND S1.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND S1.B1_TIPO = 'MP' AND SB.B2_LOCAL = '01' 
AND (CASE 
     WHEN @SALDO = 1 THEN ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) > 0) 
     ELSE ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA)>=0) END) 
ORDER BY SB.B1_DESC

erro 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

Comment: tentou fechar os parenteses na parte do OR ?

Comment: AND (((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) >= 0 AND @ SALDO = 0) OR ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) > 0 AND @ SALDO = 1))

Comment: Boa tarde Rovann, obrigado pela atenção, na query no sql funciona perfeitamente, mas quando vou para o c# ele so funciona quando esta true no chekbox.

Comment: Rovann e o seguinte deixa eu ver se consigo ser mais claro, então neste relatório tem mais 2 filtros, 1 filtro por tipo de produto e outro por armazém, quando o chekbox esta marcado todos so filtros funcionam perfeitamente, mas quando eu desmarco o chekbox, parece que o relatório não tem filtro nenhum, sendo que o filtro de tipo e armazem esta preenchido.

Comment: acho que entendi, por isso da sugestão de colocar entre parenteses o trecho que tem o OR. O operador AND sempre será executado antes do OR, e se não está corretamente separado, ele será executado somente depois de todos os AND que estão na sintaxe, podendo dar resultado true quando não são esperados.

Comment: Rovann ok deixei minha query do jeito que vc me falou, mas mesmo assim não mudou nada no c#.

Comment: veja se minha resposta te ajuda, e apenas uma observação (não está errado) na parte do cbEstoque.Checked == true, a propriedade Checked já retorna true ou false, e não é preciso a comparação ==true, poderia ser simplesmente cbEstoque.Checked ? "1" : "0";

Comment: Não mudou nada...ficou da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, mudei meu codigo para um datagridview..

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 0):

troca a parte do

```
AND (((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) >= 0 AND @SALDO = 0) OR ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) > 0 AND @SALDO = 1))
```

por:

```
AND (CASE  
     WHEN @SALDO = 1 THEN ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA) > 0)   
     ELSE ((SB.B2_QATU - SB.B2_RESERVA)>=0)
END)
```